# GUI framework for automatic resizing

Tags: user-interface, frameworks

I want to build a desktop app where the size of both the window and the content is resized automaticly according to the resolution of the monitor. I know it can be done easily with the docking features of .NET Forms, but my customer insists on going with Linux so I can't use it.

I tried Flex & Air, but the content is not resized automaticaly when I put the app in fullscreen or in another resolution (the app goes full screen but I still have tiny buttons). Now, I am looking at Qt and Gtk...

Is there a GUI framework that can do that? I don't care about the programming language.

Also, since the app will go in a bar it would be nice to be able to customize easily the skin. (like in Flex, WPF, etc.)

Regards,
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent place to start is understanding how the `Screen` class works: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx)  Even though that is .Net, it will give you an idea of how the screen size, dpi, etc. can be obtained. In addition that information should translate to the Mono platform. Since your client is insisting on Linux, you should look at MonoDevelop and then possibly the GTK# framework. My understanding is that GTK# is not a very friendly (that is *pretty*) development system (yet).

See:

1. [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
2. [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp)